# Flipping card, image on back card slow to appear on first flip

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm playing around with CSS 3D animations and I've hit a strange problem.

### What I'm doing

Created a card which has two sides, front and back, both images.

### Problem

The first time the card flips to show the back card it does not do it smoothly, you see the first card spinning around and then you see nothing for a split second and then the back card just snaps into view.

### Weird

It's only the first flip that's wrong, all other flips after it look smooth and exactly what I'm looking for.

### What I thought the problem might be

That the back image was not loaded yet by the time the first flip happened. I tried to preload the image with `JS` but it did nothing.

### JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/mz49d/

It's very annoying and I'd like to hear anyway I can fix this. I've even thrown in every vendor prefix in the CSS but it changed nothing.

### EDIT

I just tested it in FF30 and it seems to work. It does not work in my Chrome 36.0.1985.125.

Comment: I can confirm the browser difference, happens also in Chrome 35 But... if I load your JSFiddle in IE10, the second image doesn't appear at all. It's just earth, mirrored.

Comment: Yeah IE probably won't have full support for this for another 10 years. I'm just going to have to find another solution.

Comment: I'd say 10 years is optimistic.

Comment: what if you speed up animation? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mz49d/2/) animation start on hover.

Comment: @MindaugasVečkys If I slow down your demo it even works. You are a genius this is even working in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [putting the images as css-background-images](http://jsfiddle.net/mz49d/3/) works in Chrome and FF.

Not sure if there are any drawbacks to using this method on other parts of your project though...

HTML

```
<div id="card">
    <div class="card-side front-card"></div>
    <div class="card-side back-card"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.front-card {
    background: url(http://images.wisegeek.com/planet-earth.jpg);
}
.back-card {
    background: url(http://haughtonmarsproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Mars-1-Project.jpg);
}
```

Comment: What is "card-side"?